# Combine three tables with join an two with union

Tags: mysql, sql, join, merge, union

I want to combine three tables. Of which two multiple columns have to be joined together.

T1

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Carl |
| 2 | Max |
| 3 | Bob |

t2

| id | t1_id | lastname | function |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 | Johnsen | Welder |
| 6 | 2 | Clinten | Carpenter |
| 7 | 3 | Brink | Mason |

t3

| id | t2-id | Function |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 5 | Metalworking |
| 10 | 6 | Cabinet maker |
| 11 | 7 | jointer |

result

| id | name | lastname | Function |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Carl | Johnsen | Welder |
| 1 | Carl | Johnsen | Metalworking |
| 2 | Max | Clinten | Carpenter |
| 2 | Max | Clinten | Cabinet maker |
| 3 | Bob | Brink | Mason |
| 3 | Bob | Brink | jointer |

my code is

```
Select t1.id, t1.naam, t2.lastname , t3.Function 
From t1
   left join t2 on t2.t1-id=t1.[id]
   left join t3 on t3.t2-id=t2.[id],
   (Select
        Function
        from t2
        union 
        select
        Function
        from t3)t
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need  a join with subquery for union based on id

```
Select 
    t1.id, t1.naam, t2.lastname, t.Function 
From 
    t1
Left Join 
    t2 On t2.t1 - id = t1.[id]
Left Join 
    t3 On t3.t2 - id = t2.[id]
Inner Join 
    (Select id, Function
     From t2
     Union 
     Select id, Function
     From t3) t On t.id = t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking of using `union all` on two separate queries, one on two tables and one on three tables:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t2.lastname, t2.function
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.t1_id
union all
select t1.id, t1.name, t2.lastname, t3.function
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.t1_id join
     t3
     on t2.id = t3.t2_id;
```

Note that no outer joins are needed.  I am guessing that this would be better performing than an option with `union`/`union all`.